# Getting an error with 2.26 and 2.27 Selenium release while creating an Augmenter

Tags: selenium

When I create the `Augmenter` (see below) with 2.25 release of Selenium, it used to work fine. With 2.26 and 2.27 I'm getting the following error. Could you please suggest what extra is needed with a 2.26+ release to get things working again?

I get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler can not access a member of class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver with modifiers "protected"Exception caught starting Firefox webdriver

The relevant code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
```

Comment: And why is it not an option to just upgrade to Selenium 2.39.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Since newer release of selenium Agumenter only works for the RemoteWebDriver.

[It was never really supported, but now is also doesn't work](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/webdriver/12c6h5mawt/getting-an-error-with-2-26-release-while-creating-an-augmenter)

Which feature you need the Agumenter for?
I.e. to take a screenshot you can make make a direct cast of the FriefoxDriver:

```
((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

To initialize a mixed hub/local driver:

```
if (useHub) {
   ...
   webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, desiredCapabilities);
   webDriver = new Augmenter().augment(webDriver);
} else {
   switch(webDriverType) {
      case Type.FIREFOX:
         webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
      }
}
```

then use webDriver as normal